# Proof: Every subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space is finite-dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRmri.png)

The proof above is from Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*.

However, I'm not sure why Axler doesn't need to state that a linearly independent list of vectors can span all vector spaces. Or that a vector in the span of other vectors can be taken out and still have the same span.

Otherwise, can't I argue that the process doesn't necessarily terminate because there are other vectors in $U$ that have not been included in the span?

Comment: What do you mean by "a linearly independent list can span all vector spaces"? What are "all vector spaces"?

Comment: any vector space can be spanned by a linearly independent list of vectors

Comment: The proof constructs a sequence of linearly independent vectors. Since these are contained in $V$, there can be no more than $\dim V$ of them.

Comment: @stan.park712 No it can't be. The list $(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)$ is linearly independent in $R^3$ but does not span $R^3$.

Comment: @copper.hat But why does that imply $U$ is a finite-dimensional vector space? All I can deduce is that $U$ has a finite list of vectors that are linearly independent. There is nothing that states that these linearly independent vectors will span $U$. Couldn't you argue that there is an infinite number of vectors in $U$ that would make the list linearly dependent?

Comment: @Seeker Perhaps I should have said there exists a linearly independent list of vectors that spans any vector space. Then for $R^3$ , (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1) would span $R^3$

Comment: Two things: (i) The list of vectors is finite, (ii) If the list does not span $U$ then you can find another vector $v \in U$ that is not in the previous span. So $U$ must be finite dimensional.

Comment: @copper.hat How do you know the second statement is true?

Comment: @stan.park712 If the list does not span $U$, then pick **any** $v \in U$ that is not in the previous span. If such a $v$ does not exist then the span must equal $U$.

Comment: I see. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are constructing a list consisting of vectors from $U$ that is linearly independent. Since every linearly independent list in $U$ is linearly independent in $V$, this list that you are constructing cannot be any longer than the basis of $V$(by theorem $2.23$ of the book). Thus, the process terminates. This termination of the process implies that $U$ is finite dimensional as if $U$ were infinite-dimensional, then this process would never stop as no finite list spans an infinite dimensional vector space. Have a look at theorem $2.23$ of the book, it is a very important theorem.